# What would be an example of a 3-connected graph which has no edge that can be deleted to keep 3-connectivity

Tags: graph-theory

What would be an example of a 3-connected graph which has no edge that can be deleted to keep 3-connectivity? I've interpreted this as find a 3-connected graph where no edge can be deleted without destroying 3-connectivity but I am having problems visualizing a suitable graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete graph $K_4$ with 4 vertices has connectivity 3, but no edge can be deleted without destroying 3-connectivity.